# Nspredicate issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a data like that having comma separated
(sample dict below)

```
NSMutableArray *sessions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
demodata * sess = [[demodata alloc] init];  --->nsobject    
sess.Day=@"Monday";    
sess.content=@"HI";    
sess.id=@"1,2,3";    
[sessions addObject :sess];
[sess release];   

demodata * sess1 = [[demodata alloc] init];  
    
sess1.Day=@"Tuesday";    
sess1.content=@"Bye";    
sess.id=@"1,5";  
[sessions addObject :sess1];          
[sess1 release];
```

I want to display data  of id having 1(depends on dynamic) only;

**For Example: my tableview has a list of event every event has one id.
for eg if  I select id=1 i want to display the two objects(1 having 1st and 2nd object) mentioned above.if i select id=5 i want to display the second objects only(5 having 2nd object only) mentioned above.**

.(I tried nspredicate and reading every index ,split by comma).Is there any easy way to filter

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You should add some example.

Comment: and filter by what information?

Comment: @vikingosegundo  filter by id (Every id has a list of data)

Comment: How do you want to sort the id fields? I mean sorted data should lie in some relation (for example "1,2,3" > "1,5"). How do you compare the keys?

Comment: you will have to explain, what filtering by a list means for you (highest digit, mean value, number of digits,…)

Comment: @vikingosegundo check my edited ques

Answer (score 0):

`id` is an Objective-C reserved word for a pointer to an object of unknown type. I'd advise against using it as a property of a custom class. Even if it technically works, which it might not, it will be confusing.

I'm still unsure what you want, but casting to the NSString* it is might help.

```
((NSString*) ((demodata*)[sessions objectAtIndex:0]).id) //do something with this NSString*
```

Rather than trying to parse the NSString for commas, perhaps make the property an NSSArray* that holds each number as a separate index (wrap them in an instance of `NSNumber` first).

Answer (score 0):

As you did only give very vague informations about the requirements, I will show a very generic approach I am using with blocks:

write a category on array:

```
-(NSArray *)filter:(BOOL (^)(id))filterBlock
{
    NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for (id element in self) 
        if (filterBlock(element))   
            [filteredArray addObject:element]; 
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:filteredArray]; 
}
```

Now you have the freedom to create a specific block matching your needs:

```
array = [array filter:^BOOL(id element) {
    DemoData *demoData =(DemoData *)element
    if([[demoData.sessionID componentsSeparatedByString:@","] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        return YES
    }
    return NO;
}];
```

This would filter all sessionIDs starting with '1'.

**response to edit**
You should do it the other way around. You should have a NSDictionray, that uses NSNumber as keys and holds NSArrays with the objects. Than you just can ask `NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]]`. Now array holds all objets connected to the id (that you really should name differently).

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamic, then use `predicateWithBlock`.  If you want to filter a collection of `demodata` objects whose `id` contains **1**, then your [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) should look like this:

```
NSPredicate *filterWhereIdContains1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings){
           demodata *sess = (demodata*)evaluatedObject;
           NSArray *splitIds = [sess.id componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
           return [splitIds containsObject:@"1"];
}];
```